# How to NOT skip empty rows when reading Excel sheet?

Tags: c#, excel

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read an Excel file.

The problem I am having is that when reading, it counts the first row that has information as row 1. So, if the first row to have information is row 3, it counts that as the first row. This is a problem because the Excel sheets sometimes have data on the first 2 rows, sometimes they don't. But the data I need to read always starts on the third row.

Here is the routine I am using to read the sheets:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbooks wkbs = exl.Workbooks;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wkb = null;
        Sheets shts;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wks = null;

        // load work book
        //wkb = wkbs.Open(races_data_path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);//oMissing
        wkb = wkbs.Open(races_data_path, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);//oMissing

        shts = wkb.Sheets;
        wks = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)shts.get_Item(Properties.Settings.Default.excel_worksheet);

        // read lines from worksheet
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = wks.UsedRange;

        for (int rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
        {
            try
            {
                object[,] values = (object[,])range.Value2;

                if (Convert.ToString(values[rCnt, 4]) != "")
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Ldd: {0} {1} {2}", Convert.ToInt16(values[rCnt, 2]), Convert.ToInt16(values[rCnt, 3]), Convert.ToString(values[rCnt, 4])));
                    if (races[Convert.ToInt16(values[rCnt, 1])] == null) races[Convert.ToInt16(values[rCnt, 1])] = new RaceObject();

                    races[Convert.ToInt16(values[rCnt, 1])].add_racer(Convert.ToInt16(values[rCnt, 2]), Convert.ToInt16(values[rCnt, 3]), Convert.ToString(values[rCnt, 4]), Convert.ToString(values[rCnt, 7]));
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                data_loaded = false;
                rCnt = range.Rows.Count;
            }

        }
```

This example, you can see the loop count starts at '1'. This was for reading a sheet where the first 2 lines of the sheet were empty. If the first 2 lines have data, then this loop only works if I change the count start to '3'.

For example:
The start value = 1 if the sheet looks like this:

```
no data
no data
has data
has data
has data
```

The start value = 3 if the sheet looks like this:

```
has unnecessary data
has unnecessary data
has data
has data
has data
```

Comment: Try using `wks.Cells` for your `Range` instead of `wks.UsedRange`

Comment: Thanks petelids. I changed that value but get an Out of Memory error at this line: object[,] values = (object[,])range.Value2;

Comment: Also, I tried using the  wks.Rows as well and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Add something to the first cell immediately before doing the rest: wks.cells(1, 1).value = "'" & wks.cells(1, 1).value This will extend the usedRange to the first cell.

Then the data will always start on the third row and you can easily always skip the first two rows.

Option 2: You can also use `wks.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Row` to see whether the first row is 1 or 3. Then you can adjust whether you use those rows or not.

(Edited post based on comments)

Comment: Thanks. But I think you misunderstood the problem(or I'm not being clear). The problem is what Excel is calling the first available row. Basically, it seems to call the first row that has data the first available row rather than the first physical row in the sheet. So, if the first 2 rows are empty, it is calling the third row the first available row.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all your C# but it seems you must be getting the usedrange somehow. Try adding something to the first cell immediately before doing the rest: `wks.cells(1, 1).value = "'" & wks.cells(1, 1).value` This will extend the usedRange to the first cell.

Comment: That's a bit of a 'dirty' solution, but it seems to work. Thanks D_Bester.

Comment: You can also check the row number of the UsedRange; see edit.

Comment: I tried your option 2. There does not seem to be a c# equivalent to that. Although that would be a better solution, the first one works for my needs here.

Comment: Seems to me this is not a c# thing but an Excel thing. Curious what error you got?

Comment: Oops! I had ws instead of wks in option 2.

Comment: The c# version should be something like wks.UsedRange.Cells[1.1].Row. However, after the Cells[1,1], 'Row' is not an option. I did try Cells.Row, which, according to the hint , should have given me a row number but it didn't.